# Как объединить две программы?

Tags: python

Есть программа для raspberry pi, для чтения списка файлов с флешки и вывода их на монохромный дисплей, список на экране можно листать тактовыми кнопками. Нужно объеденить ее с программой Printrun (Pronterface). Сначала поместил код моей программы вне класса. Потом поместил в класс ConsoleOutputHandler. Но ни кнопки, ни дисплей не работают в обоих случаях. Что делать? Ниже прикрепляю четыре файла:1) программа для работы с дисплеем; три варианта Pronterface - 2)исходная; 3) с кодом моей программы вне класса; 4) в классе.
http://rgho.st/6Gqhm6spJ
И ещё ссылка на полные исходники printrun на всякий случай  https://github.com/kliment/Printrun

Comment: свой код лучше поместить на [pastebin](http://pastebin.com), а также приведите ошибки работы вашей программы.

Comment: я тоже не пойму в чем проблема. Или проблема в том, что автор не умеет писать код и просит объединить 2 чужих проекта?

Comment: @approximatenumber pastebin не нужно предлагать. Вместо этого следует создать *минимальный*, но полный пример кода, который показывает проблему и поместить его в вопрос (несколько строчек на каждую программу должно быть достаточно, остальной код на заглушки следует заменить). [mcve]